# Is a join appropriate for accomplishing such functionality in LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, join

I'm writing an ASP.NET MVC site where I'm using LINQ to SQL to access my SQL Server database. In my database, I have the following tables:

***Posts***:

- PostID - int, PK, identity
- Text - nvarchar(MAX)
- PublishDate - datetime
- *etc.*

***PostTags***:

- PostTagID - int, PK, identity
- PostID - FK to PK to Posts table
- TagID - FK to PK to Tags table

***Tags***:

- TagID - int, PK, identity
- TagName - varchar(100)

Each Post must have at least 1 Tag, so it's a **single-to-many** relationship.

I'm trying to build a tag search function. I want to **accept a Tag as a parameter** and **return the first 25 Posts that have that tag**, ordered by PublishDate descending. Here's my current LINQ to SQL code:

```
    var query = (from post in db.Posts
                join posttag in db.PostTags
                on post.PostID equals posttag.PostID
                where posttag.Tag.TagName==tag
                select post).OrderByDescending(p=>p.DateOfPublish).Take(25);
```

However, I think that my code is wrong, because it doesn't seem to respect the single-to-many relationship between Posts and Tags.

How can I improve my code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rather than simply saying "it doesn't work", you should post your expected results and what you actually got.

Comment: @Adam I haven't tested the code, but I am pretty sure that it won't work because there may be multiple records in PostTags with the same PostID.

Comment: My money's on data. Can you give us some sample records and show which of the records (if any) are returned?

Comment: What you describe is a many-to-many relationship, because a post can relate to many tags and vice versa--a tag can relate to many posts.

Comment: @OMGPonies true, Posts to Tags is many-to-many; however, Posts to PostTags is single-to-many, right?

Comment: Only if you limit the scope so that you don't look at the relationships on the `POSTTAGS` table...

Comment: @Maxim: Technically, yes, since there's no such thing as an actual m:m relationship on anything other than a conceptual level (m:m in reality requires to m:1 relationships on an intermediate table, which is exactly what you have), but @OMG is correct. In any case, I'm not sure why you'd post here before you test the code. Try it out and if it doesn't give you the expected results (honestly, it looks fine to me, assuming that you would never have duplicate records in `PostTags`), then come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = (from post in db.Posts 
            where(
                    from posttag in db.PostTags
                    join tags in db.Tags
                    on posttag.TagID equals tags.TagID   
                    where tags.TagName == tag select posttag.PostID
                ).Contains(post.PostID) 
            orderby post.PublishDate descending 
            select post).Take(25);
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks, going to try it out now. By the way, Visual Studio is complaining that the "on ..." line should be "on posttag.TagID equals tags.TagID".

Comment: @Maxim Zaslavsky really? for me it's the big news. thank you (fixed).

Comment: I can't see how this could possibly be better than the original code unless `PostTags` can have duplicate records (in which case you have a problem with your design).